# Stunnel from HTTP client to HTTPS web service >Malformed content (from client)<

Tags: ssl

What is wrong with my stunnel ?

**Web service on port 8810:**
[https://somehost.com:8810/test-service]

**Soap client on port 3600:**
[http://localhost:3600/test-service]

**stunnel.conf:**

```
options = NO_SSLv3 
options = NO_TLSv1  
sslVersion = TLSv1.2
verify = 0  
client = yes 

[https] 
accept = 127.0.0.1:3600
connect = somehost.com:8810 
CAfile = cis-root.pem  ->  Server CA root  
cert = stunnel.pem
```

**I always get the error in the answer?**
    
    env:Client
    Malformed content (from client)

**stunnel.log**

```
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[cron]: Cron thread initialized  
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: Running on Windows 6.2
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: No limit detected for the number of clients 
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG5[main]: stunnel 5.35 on x86-pc-msvc-1500 platform  
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG5[main]: Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.0.2h-fips  3 May 2016
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG5[main]: Threading:WIN32 Sockets:SELECT,IPv6 TLS:ENGINE,FIPS,OCSP,PSK,SNI
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: errno: (*_errno())
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[ui]: GUI message loop initialized
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: Running on Windows 6.2
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG5[main]: Reading configuration from file stunnel.conf
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG5[main]: UTF-8 byte order mark detected
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG5[main]: FIPS mode disabled
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: Compression disabled
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: PRNG seeded successfully
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG6[main]: Initializing service [https]
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG6[main]: Loading certificate from file: stunnel.pem
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG6[main]: Certificate loaded from file: stunnel.pem
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG6[main]: Loading private key from file: stunnel.pem
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG6[main]: Private key loaded from file: stunnel.pem
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: Private key check succeeded
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG4[main]: Service [https] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: SSL options: 0x07000004 (+0x07000000, -0x00000000)
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG5[main]: Configuration successful
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: Listening file descriptor created (FD=660)
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: Option SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE set on accept socket
2016.07.23 08:52:59 LOG7[main]: Service [https] (FD=660) bound to 127.0.0.1:3600
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[main]: Found 1 ready file descriptor(s)
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[main]: FD=588 ifds=r-x ofds=---
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[main]: Service [https] accepted (FD=708) from 127.0.0.1:54602
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[main]: Creating a new thread
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[main]: New thread created
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Service [https] started
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on local socket
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG5[0]: Service [https] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:54602
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: s_connect: connecting 185.20.28.208:8810
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: s_connect: s_poll_wait 185.20.28.208:8810: waiting 10 seconds
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG5[0]: s_connect: connected 185.20.28.208:8810
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG5[0]: Service [https] connected remote server from 192.168.7.199:54603
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on remote socket
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Remote descriptor (FD=724) initialized
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: SNI: sending servername: samehost.com
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: Peer certificate not required
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write client hello A
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server hello A
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: Certificate verification disabled
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: Certificate verification disabled
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server certificate A
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: Client certificate not requested
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server done A
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write client key exchange A
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write finished A
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 flush data
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read finished A
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]:      1 client connect(s) requested
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]:      1 client connect(s) succeeded
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]:      0 client renegotiation(s) requested
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]:      0 session reuse(s)
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: Negotiated TLSv1.2 ciphersuite AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256-bit encryption)
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Compression: null, expansion: null
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL alert (read): warning: close notify
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: SSL closed (SSL_read)
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Sent socket write shutdown
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: Read socket closed (readsocket)
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Sending close_notify alert
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: SSL alert (write): warning: close notify
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG6[0]: SSL_shutdown successfully sent close_notify alert
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG5[0]: Connection closed: 708 byte(s) sent to SSL, 382 byte(s) sent to socket
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Remote descriptor (FD=724) closed
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Local descriptor (FD=708) closed
2016.07.23 08:53:28 LOG7[0]: Service [https] finished (0 left)
```

Comment: Based on the logs there is no problem with the TLS stack. So the problem might be at the SOAP level which is not visible here.

Comment: SOAP is well-tested XML that works with apache where over curl gets the correct answer from the same web service

Comment: Thank a lot for your comment, I debug communication, apache processing SOAP xml on the other way. I corrected the SOAP header and everything works ..